# Assign "ctrl + space" behavior on jtable selection to another key

Tags: java, jtable

**I want to be able to navigate a JTable and select multiple non-consecutive rows by pressing the numpad "+" key instead of "ctrl+space".**

First I tried multiple codes using changeSelection, addRowSelectionInterval and setRowSelectionInterval, but I wasn't able to do the exact behavioer as using "ctrl + space".

So I realized it would be easier for me to try and change that behavior on JTable. I think I can navigate through the code to find the class code, but I can't find it. I guess it isnt as simple as I'm thinking..

Please give me an insight on the problem. Thank you!!

---

Update:

My idea is set "up" and "down" to make exactly what "ctrl+up" and "ctrl+down" does when navigating the JTable, that is, be able to press "space" and select multiple non-contiguous cells.

The Code:

```
    KeyStroke ctrlUpKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    KeyStroke ctrlDownKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    KeyStroke upKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
    KeyStroke downKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);

    InputMap im = jTabelaConsumo.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

    im.put(upKeyStroke, im.get(ctrlUpKeyStroke));
    im.put(downKeyStroke, im.get(ctrlDownKeyStroke));
```

Comment: You'll need to assign new [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and when triggered manipulate the selection, either via the table or via the selection model

Comment: Yes. I'll need to change the keybinding of it. But the problem is: what will that action call? I don't know what is the 'ctrl+space' function doing for me to call it on my keyAction

Comment: System.out.println("im = " + im.allKeys().length); <- Always returning NULL.

Comment: - System.out.println("im = " + im.size());
-> im = 0

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know what is the 'ctrl+space' function doing for me to call it on my keyAction –

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of the default key bindings for each component.

It will also show you how to share the Action with a different key binding.

Comment: Copying the action put me into the right direction, but It isn't working yet!

Comment: @FelipeCarminati, Did you check out the KeyBindings program I linked you to? It looks to me like you are using the wrong InputMap. All the bindings are done to the "ancestor" map, not the focused map.